# Entity Framework Primary Key Design (Human Resources web app)

Tags: entity-framework, extjs, database-design, asp.net-web-api

I'm going to start the development for a Human Resources (HRMS) application and I have been thinking about choosing the best datatype for database primary keys.

The application has a few must to have's:

- JavaScript Framework (ExtJS)
- ASP.NET WebAPI Server Side
- Multi-Tenant feature (database design)

I have developed other enterprise applications before using Entity Framework and incremental `INT` as primary keys but sometimes you get into trouble when dealing with manual imports, etc. because the primary key is dynamic.

So I have been thinking on using `GUID`s as primary key because it gives you a lot of benefits in terms on data management but would like to know how does that perform with Entity Framework. Is there any side-effect on using GUID as primary keys in all my tables?

The only down-side element that I can think on using `GUID`s on server side is the `Payload` to the client because then each jSON sent from server to client will have a `GUID` on each record (36 chars instead of simple INT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No downside I know of besides it can be harder to debug when trying to compare Guid's. (integers are easier to read). The major benefit I see is that you don't need to have the table locked when doing inserts because you simply say "Guid.new" (something like that) and it is practically guaranteed to be unique.

I use Guid's all the time as my primary key with EF so I'm sure it works very well.  Unless your tables records are very very short,  I don't think the length is of material concern.

My 2 cents.